# Bugs after Magento 2 Installation

Tags: magento2, installation, magento-2.0

I've noticed a couple of bugs with my Magento 2 installation.

1. When loading the home page or admin of my website, it seems to keep refreshing itself for a while and takes up to a minute to load. It doesn't appear to be a performance issue with my computer because Magento 1.9 runs smoothly.
2. When I clear the cache, all images, Javascript and CSS stop working. Running `php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy` does restore the locations of these missing files but it sets incorrect file/directory permissions.

Am I doing something wrong here? I get similar problems when trying to run Magento 2 using XAMPP on my local machine.

Answer (score -1):

permissions are probably correct, but wrong user. you have to edit files with correct user who runs php and webserver must have read permisions:

```
su <files owner> -s /bin/bash -c "magento setup:static-content:deploy"
```

and change owner for root magento folder as well.

```
chown -R <files owner>:<files owner> magento_folder/*
```

Comment: I have to do that every time I clear Magento's cache? That doesn't seem right, I don't have any problems with Magento 1.x installations.

Comment: no you dont have to chmod files every time. only once, but run all commands as web user/file owner.

Answer (score -2):

Install Composer. Now I would like you to download Magento 2 zip from `magentocommerce.com/download`, create new **db** in **phpmyadmin**, extract zip in **htdocs** folder. Install Magento 2 but do not use **localhost** use **127.0.0.1** in store URL and admin URL. After successful installation **DO NOT** run magento.

Now we are going to verify Composer installation, Deploy static content, clear / flush Magento cache and reindex the Magento 2 blocks. To perform all above actions, press WINDOWS KEY + R to open RUN dialog and type “cmd” to open Command Prompt.

Type “**cd PATH_TO_YOUR_MAGENTO2_FILES**” to enter in Magento 2 ROOT directory.

Now to verify Composer installation in above directory, type “**composer install**”.

> If you get any error in this step, please check your Composer
>   installation

In this step, we are setting up static content to deploy on our Magento store. To perform this, type “**php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy**”.

> If you get any error, check your PHP.EXE and PHP.INI Environment
>   Variable

Clear / Flush Magento cache by typing “**php bin/magento cache:flush**” in CMD.

And finally, to Reindex Magento Static Blocks type “**php bin/magento indexer:reindex**”.

You are done with successful installation of Magento 2.

Comment: Answer has been edited.

Comment: why are you trying to hide any traces of your original answer????

Comment: @MagenX everyone have right to solve his mistake, not a people like you who take everything seriously. Grow up please.