# Magento 2 admin panel issue

Tags: magento2, magento-2.0

I install Magento 2, but i have one problem, after i login in the Admin Panel, my admin is look very strange. And i see the frontend is the same. Any idea why?

[image]

[image]

Comment: http://magento.stackexchange.com/a/96904/31999

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need just permission in pub static folder for example :

```
chmod -R 777 pub/*
```

if not :

```
php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy
```

and

```
chmod -R 777 pub/*
```

Comment: perfect lbnab, thank you so much, is work like charm